# How to check a file's MIME type

Tags: perl, mime

I am working with *Koha* — An Integrated Library System (ILS) written in Perl. I need to check the MIME type of each uploaded file for security purposes.

Some search results from Google suggest that we can do it with the help of the [`File::MimeInfo`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MimeInfo) Perl module.

How can we install the `File::MimeInfo` module in Koha and check the MIME types, or is there some better way?

Comment: [Look into this](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/How_to_install_missing_Perl_modules_on_Debian)

Comment: If you are hoping to prevent malicious attacks then `File::MimeInfo` won't help you much. All it does is guess a MIME type from the name of the file, which is trivial to spoof.

Comment: Are you having problems with the Perl documentation? I think it is particularly clear about how to install a module, and you should describe what you have read that you don't understand.

Comment: The project which we currently working on is a government/PSU project, so we have to implement certain security feature like MIME Type checking.

Comment: We find no issues in installing MIME module in perl , but when it comes to KOHA (written in perl) we could not install the MimeInfo module.

Comment: You don't install a module into an application - you install it into the Perl system. Do you have multiple Perl installations? And you're missing my point about MIME types. If you have a file called `file.jpg` then `File::MimeInfo` will tell you that it has a MIME type of `image/jpeg` regardless of what it contains. It may be an executable file containing a virus, and the module won't notice. If a hacker only has to rename the file to get past your security then it's no security at all.

Comment: As said in another comment File::MimeInfo only does a guess based on the filename. If you want to actually analyse the file, you could look at File::MMagic::XS. I've never heard of ILS, so I have no idea how you could integrate it into that.

Comment: I implemented  File::MMagic::XS in ILS-KOHA. But it will always return 'text/plain' when I upload jpg,pdf and png files.Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I use is [Image::ExifTool](http://search.cpan.org/~exiftool/Image-ExifTool-10.40/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod) it can do a format check on some of the mime types and point out files with errors. Its not made as a security  program so it can have some faults in that area, but its an active distribution.

You can install the module by placing the folder /lib in the modules tarball on the server then add this line of Perl code to your script `use lib '/path/to/lib';` .